# error in ibatis 3 (db2 database) while executing a query . it runs fine from sql client

Tags: sql, database, db2

This is my query

```
SELECT DEFAULT2.DAY_NO AS DAY ,
DEFAULT2.WHSE_WKNG_DAY_IND AS WAREHOUSEWORKINGDAY ,
VALUE(CASE WHEN (DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND='Y') THEN DEFAULT2.XPRES_CUTOFF_TIME ELSE
(SELECT DISTINCT(GREATEST(CNTRY.XPRESCUTOF_SHAW,CNTRY.XPRESCUTOF_NONSHAW,DEPOT.XPRESCUTOF_SHAW,DEPOT.XPRESCUTOF_NONSHAW))
FROM T_XPR_CNTRY_GRP CNTRY ,T_XPR_DEPOT_GRP DEPOT) END ,DEF2.XPRES_CUTOFF_TIME) AS EXPRESSCUTOFFTIME
FROM T_WHSEXPRESCUTOF DEFAULT2
INNER JOIN T_WHSEXPRESCUTOF DEF2 ON DEFAULT2.DAY_NO = DEF2.DAY_NO
ORDER BY DEFAULT2.DAY_NO WITH UR
```

When i run this through ibatis 3 (with annotations) my database is db2 I get the error

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement then 'DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND' is not a column in the target table.
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.IbatisException: .....

The same query runs fine through sql clients like squirrel. I have checked there are no access permission issues. .

Is this a bug in Ibatis ? I have posted the same on mybatis3 issues.

The ibatis code is below

```
@Select(value = {
            "SELECT "+                                                             
                 "DEFAULT2.DAY_NO AS DAY "+                                            
                 ",DEFAULT2.WHSE_WKNG_DAY_IND AS WAREHOUSEWORKINGDAY"+                 
                 ",VALUE( "+                                                           
                 "CASE  "+                                  
                 "WHEN (DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND='Y') THEN "+                                                    
                 "   DEFAULT2.XPRES_CUTOFF_TIME "+                                     
                 "ELSE "+                                                             
                 "  (SELECT DISTINCT(GREATEST(CNTRY.XPRESCUTOF_SHAW" +
                         ",CNTRY.XPRESCUTOF_NONSHAW"+                  
                        ",DEPOT.XPRESCUTOF_SHAW"+                     
                        ",DEPOT.XPRESCUTOF_NONSHAW)) "+                
                 "    FROM T_XPR_CNTRY_GRP CNTRY "+                               
                 "        ,T_XPR_DEPOT_GRP DEPOT) "+                               
                 "END "+                                                             
                 ",DEF2.XPRES_CUTOFF_TIME) AS EXPRESSCUTOFFTIME "+  
           "FROM T_WHSEXPRESCUTOF DEFAULT2 "+                                 
           "INNER JOIN T_WHSEXPRESCUTOF DEF2 "+                              
           "ON DEFAULT2.DAY_NO = DEF2.DAY_NO "+                                    
           "ORDER BY DEFAULT2.DAY_NO "+                                            
           "WITH UR"
    })
    @Results({
        @Result(property="warehouseWorkingDay", jdbcType=JdbcType.CHAR,typeHandler=YesNoBooleanTypeHandler.class, column="WAREHOUSEWORKINGDAY"),
        @Result(property="day", jdbcType=JdbcType.INTEGER,typeHandler= IntegerTypeHandler.class, column="DAY"),
        @Result(property="expressCutOffTime", jdbcType=JdbcType.DATE,typeHandler=DateTypeHandler.class, column="EXPRESSCUTOFFTIME")        
    })
    List<CutOffTimeImpl> getCutOffTimes();
```

Issues

- On executing the above query i get the exception Cause:
  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column
  'DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND' is either not in any table in the FROM
  list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope
  of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in
  the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then
  'DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND' is not a column in the target table.
                                  org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.IbatisException:
- I just changed the case expression to 1=1 to see if it is the only
  issue but further down it reports that 'T_XPR_CNTRY_GRP' is not a
  table/view
- My initial doubt was if it was a access right issue but the DBA have
  confirmed that there is no such constraint/restriction
- My final doubt is if iBATIS is expecting every column that is part of
  the select to be mapped to a resulting column which would be weird.
  In this case we can't do so because the final out put of
  Value(equivalent of nvl statement in oracle) and case statement is
  fetched as EXPRESSCUTOFFTIME   and this is mapped to the resultset
  objects field.I got this doubt because when i replaced the expression
  DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND ='Y' with DAY DEFAULT2.DAY='Y'  on a
  trial basis this error(point2 above) goes of.

A more detail log

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement then 'DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND' is not a column in the target table.

at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved, we were usign a in memory derby database (in dev and test enviroment) to stub data and few columns that were reported as not part of the select were not present in the in memory database table. The table which was reported as 'not a table/view'  did not exist in the in memory database too.

Ours is a very big application it was hard to figure this out. Now i have added the columns/tables that populates the derby in memory database as part of the start up script.

I avoided using Greatest() function too as it was not compatible with derby, the query that worked fine finally is

```
    SELECT                                                              
         DEFAULT2.DAY_NO AS DAY                                             
         ,DEFAULT2.WHSE_WKNG_DAY_IND AS WAREHOUSEWORKINGDAY                 
         ,VALUE(                                                            
         CASE                                    
         WHEN DEFAULT2.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_IND='Y' THEN                                                     
            DEFAULT2.XPRES_CUTOFF_TIME                                      
         ELSE 
          (SELECT DISTINCT(
             SELECT MAX(maxquery.cutoff) 
            FROM 
              (SELECT CNTRY.XPRESCUTOF_SHAW AS cutoff 
               FROM T_XPR_CNTRY_GRP CNTRY 
               UNION  
               SELECT CNTRY.XPRESCUTOF_NONSHAW AS cutoff 
               FROM T_XPR_CNTRY_GRP CNTRY 
               UNION  
               SELECT DEPOT.XPRESCUTOF_SHAW AS cutoff 
               FROM T_XPR_DEPOT_GRP DEPOT 
               UNION  
               SELECT DEPOT.XPRESCUTOF_NONSHAW AS cutoff 
               FROM T_XPR_DEPOT_GRP DEPOT                  
               ) maxquery 
              ) FROM T_XPR_CNTRY_GRP CNTRY,T_XPR_DEPOT_GRP DEPOT 
          ) 
         END                                                              
         ,DEF2.XPRES_CUTOFF_TIME) AS EXPRESSCUTOFFTIME   
   FROM T_WHSEXPRESCUTOF DEFAULT2                                  
   INNER JOIN T_WHSEXPRESCUTOF DEF2                               
   ON DEFAULT2.DAY_NO = DEF2.DAY_NO                                     
   ORDER BY DEFAULT2.DAY_NO                                             
   WITH UR
```

Sorry if i made you spend lot of time to figure this out.